# .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0. There was a failure initializing profiling API attach infrastructure.

Tags: wcf, iis, event-log, eventlog-source

Lately I started noticing "**.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - There was a failure initializing profiling API attach infrastructure.  This process will not allow a profiler to attach.  HRESULT: 0x80004005.  Process ID (decimal): 10288.  Message ID: [0x2509].**" on our production Windows Server R2.

This server is mainly used for IIS hosted WCF service. I googled about the error and found multiple solutions and I tried below.

1) Verified .NET framework with Microsoft's utility and no issues found. That means one of the application is firing this .NET error.

2) Tried tracking process id, but everytime error message has different process id. And I cannot find the pid from all available pid. My assumption is, it recycles the process after error and assign new pid.

What is the best technique to find source of this error? Is there anyway I can get pid history logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked all the recently installed softwares and uninstalled the ones which was installed after the first error date.

For me, it was Wireshark, after uninstalling I do not see this error anymore.

Cheers!